# Date axis overlapping and unclean graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

[image: 1]
code:

```
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(SSN_x, SSN_y, 'o-')
plt.title('SSN/Dpse')
plt.ylabel('SSN')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(Dose_x,Dose_y, '.-')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Dose')

plt.show()
```

The x label is in year-month-day. any way of making it look cleaner like resize or something to show the 2 graphs are anti-correlation?
maybe show only 1st day of a year i.e. 2020-01-01 on the label? so it won't be overcrowded.

Comment: This problem gets posted at least twice a week.

Comment: Yes i know, I have tried solutions from other posts, i.e rotate the label. still does not help

Comment: convert your strings to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

I used `mdates.date2num'`to convert `str` to `matplotlib_datetime`.